# updating glibc on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: package-management, software-installation, glibc

I'm trying to script an installation of geany and might be on my 20th failure (then like L'Hopital, I shall fail to fail). There's a lot of scripting involved, and I'm only halfway through addressing the issues of missing files.

This [Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=721860) suggests that maybe the ultimate value in this list is what I need:

```
$ sudo apt  search libglib | grep dev

libglib2.0-cil-dev/xenial 2.12.10-6 amd64
libglib2.0-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.48.2-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libglib3.0-cil-dev/xenial 2.99.3-2 amd64
libglibmm-2.4-dev/xenial 2.46.3-1 amd64
  C++ wrapper for the GLib toolkit (development files)
```

Then I go ahead and try it anyways:

```
$ sudo apt install libglibmm-2.4-dev
[sudo] password for bob: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-27 linux-headers-4.10.0-27-generic
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
...
Selecting previously unselected package libglibmm-2.4-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libglibmm-2.4-dev_2.46.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglibmm-2.4-dev:amd64 (2.46.3-1) ...
Setting up libsigc++-2.0-dev:amd64 (2.6.2-1) ...
Setting up libglibmm-2.4-dev:amd64 (2.46.3-1) ...
```

but,

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu10) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
....
```

This is the output from the install of geany:

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.24 glib-2.0 >= 2.32 gio-2.0 >= 2.32 gmodule-no-export-2.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have to say that I do not understand *exactly* what it means. If it means that it found 2.0 and needs 2.4, then I would understand.

Also, I find no way to post code doesn't make the whole post unreadable. If I could indent my code 4 spaces, then I wouldn't need to install geany.

Comment: Why do you think `glibc` is the issue here? it appears to be complaining about  `gtk+-2.0` - did you install the `libgtk2.0-dev` package? BTW why are you trying to install geany from source rather than using the packaged version from the repository?

Comment: thx steeldriver, your response makes me believe that I was over-reacting on glibc. I have never had particularly good luck with gui versions of linux package managers. Since other, more experienced users have no problem with it all, I'm sure the issue is that I don't know how to give it the right instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the problem you are having is that you are trying and failing to install `geany` as mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002219/updating-glibc-on-ubuntu-16-04-3-lts#comment1620937_1002219) it's not necessary to compile it as a quick search of [Ubuntu Package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) makes it clear that the package is available in the Universe repository for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install, simply [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then issue the commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install geany
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know state of the official repositories on your system, so enable them again and fix previous failures:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

- If you need any version of Geany (such as 1.27.1 on xenial), you can install it from [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
  ```
- Geany [has PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geany-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial), you can install more recent version (1.32) from it:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
  ```

Comment: This seems to have gotten me most of the way. I compiled these commands into a script:

https://github.com/TBlazer66/island/blob/master/1.repos.sh